# How to split images into two folders using name of the image in python?

Tags: python

I have a folder of images containing

```
['PAT_01_01_crypts.png',

'PAT_01_01_orig.png',

'PAT_01_02_crypts.png',

'PAT_01_02_orig.png',

'PAT_01_03_crypts.png',

'PAT_01_03_orig.png']
```

I want to split these images into two folders.

Folder 1:

```
PAT_01_01_crypts.png

PAT_01_02_crypts.png

PAT_01_03_crypts.png
```

Folder 2:

```
PAT_01_01_orig.png

PAT_01_02_orig.png

PAT_01_03_orig.png
```

Can you please help me out. Im also trying to augment these images.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `in` keyword to check whether the certain string in the statement.

```
A = ['PAT_01_01_crypts.png', 'PAT_01_01_orig.png', 'PAT_01_02_crypts.png',
     'PAT_01_02_orig.png', 'PAT_01_03_crypts.png', 'PAT_01_03_orig.png']


folder1 = []
folder2 = []

for name in A:
    if "orig" in name:
        folder1.append(name)
    else:
        folder2.append(name)

print(folder1)
print(folder2)
```

or you can use:

```
folder1 = [name for name in A if "orig" in name]
folder2 = [name for name in A if "crypt" in name]
```

Both Output:

```
['PAT_01_01_orig.png', 'PAT_01_02_orig.png', 'PAT_01_03_orig.png']
['PAT_01_01_crypts.png', 'PAT_01_02_crypts.png', 'PAT_01_03_crypts.png']
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `shutil`library combined with `glob` library

```
import shutil
import os
import glob


path = os.path.join('src','data','images','*')
#use your own path
list_files = glob.glob(path)
for file in list_files:
  if file.endswith('orig.png'):
     shutil.move(file,os.path.join('src','data','target','')
  else:
     shutil.move(file,os.path.join('src','data','target2','')
```

> `glob.glob(path)` will return a list containing all the files / folder that are in path. Note that to do so you need the `*` at the end of your path

`shutil.move()`
go to https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-shutil-move-method/ for details

I have not tested it, so tell me if it works

Comment: Thank you for your quick response!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a novice approach to the problem. The approach is simple but accounts for any number of `image types` (orig, crypt etc..)

### Code

```
import os 
import shutil 

image_type = ['orig', 'crypt', 'hd', 'sd']
files_list = ['PAT_01_01_crypts.png', 'PAT_01_02_crypts.png', 'PAT_01_03_crypts.png', 'PAT_01_01_orig.png', 'PAT_01_02_orig.png', 'PAT_01_03_orig.png', 'myfile_hd.png', 'yourfile_sd.png']

# Check if directory exists. If not, create it
for folder in image_type:
    if os.path.isdir(f"./{folder}"):
        pass
    else:
        os.mkdir(f"./{folder}")

# Move files
for fname in files_list:  # traverse the files list
    for img in image_type: # compare which type it matches to
        if img in fname:
            shutil.move(f"./{fname}", f"./{img}/{fname}") # move it to the respective directory
            break 

# Print contents of each folder
for folder in image_type:
    print(f"\n\nContents of {folder}::::")
    print(os.listdir(f"./{folder}"))
```

### Input

```
PAT_01_01_crypts.png
PAT_01_02_crypts.png
PAT_01_03_crypts.png
PAT_01_01_orig.png
PAT_01_02_orig.png
PAT_01_03_orig.png
myfile_hd.png
yourfile_sd.png
```

### Output

```
Contents of orig::::
['PAT_01_01_orig.png', 'PAT_01_02_orig.png', 'PAT_01_03_orig.png']


Contents of crypt::::
['PAT_01_01_crypts.png', 'PAT_01_02_crypts.png', 'PAT_01_03_crypts.png']


Contents of hd::::
['myfile_hd.png']


Contents of sd::::
['yourfile_sd.png']
```

Comment: Thank you for a quick response!!

Comment: Glad to help. If this or any other answer helped you, do accept and upvote. stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers